# What's wrong with this code, why can't it run

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, seaborn, kernel-density

All other code ran but when I typed the below code, it couldn't run in pycharm

```
Kde = np.sum(kernels,axis=0)
Kde_fig = plt.plot(x_axes,kde,color='green')
sns.rugplot(ds)
plt.suptitle('KDE Plot')
plt savefig('image3.png')
```

Comment: nobody will be able to help you if you do not explain in what way "it couldn't run in pycharm". Are you getting an error message? In any case, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before editing your question

Answer (score 1):

I think `plt savefig('image3.png')` needs to be changed to `plt.savefig('image3.png')`

Comment: Ok that was a mistake it's actually plt.savefig('image3.png')